# how to set username and password for xlsform

Tags: python, xls

i am using the formhub.org server to submit form data via odk collect software.
i designed the xlsform and it works correctly.
the problem is that i wanna set a username and password for form submission so everybody cant submit from until he/she knows the password.
i dont know is it possible from odk collect application or somehow in my xlsform...

```
    type                    name             label
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    text                    some_text        1. What is your full name?
    select_multiple company some_company     2. Which telecomunication companies do you use?
    select_one company      best_company     3. Which one is the best?
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

easily i did it from my formhub.org account.
in account setting there is an option for authentication for mobile i just checked it.